# How do I speed up mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance

I desperately need something to speed up this query!

This being the query, how can I add indexes to speed it up and what do I change to make the query a lot faster?

This is the actual query performed in phpmyadmin.

Showing rows 0 - 6 (7 total, Query took 6.4767 sec)

This is the same query but I am using UNION ALL to display all the results:

Showing rows 0 - 29 (23074 total, Query took 4.0590 sec)

```
SELECT `location2` as `location`, '2' as `number`
FROM `properties` 
WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 
AND `country` = 'spain' 
union 
SELECT `location3` as `location`, '3' as `number` 
FROM `properties` 
WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 
AND `location2` = 'spain' 
union 
SELECT `location4` as `location`, '4' as `number` 
FROM `properties` 
WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 
AND `location3` = 'spain' 
union 
SELECT `location5` as `location`, '5' as `number` 
FROM `properties` 
WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 AND 
`location4` = 'spain' 
union 
SELECT `location6` as `location`, '6' as `number` 
FROM `properties` 
WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 
AND `location5` = 'spain'
```

Comment: Can you show an execution plan?  Is there an index on `price_from` and (probably more importantly) `country`?

Comment: How do you want me to show the execution plan? I am new to indexes and I am not sure how do I check if the index is added ok or not? I added some indexes from phpmyadmin but I am not sure if I did it the right way. A normal query for all the DB is this: "Showing rows 0 - 29 (36984 total, Query took 0.0452 sec)" so it loads pretty fast, I just don't get it why that query takes so long to load.

Comment: This could help maybe http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24780/mysql-optimize-union-with-order-by-in-inner-queries

Comment: @Kev - Just put "EXPLAIN" in front of your query.  I'd just focus on optimizing each individual query one by one, then `UNION` them all together at the end.

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server?  you have both tagged.  They are separate RDBMS systems.

Comment: @Mike here is the execution plan: http://pastebin.com/tHAGPfEq

Comment: Can you show some sample data in sqlfiddle?While its true you are missing indexes I`m guessing this query can be made much simpler

Comment: @Mihai I don't know how to use sqlfiddle. Can anyone help me add indexes to this query to see if it loads faster?

Comment: Is this the correct way to add indexes? ALTER TABLE `trv_travel`.`properties` DROP INDEX `country` ,
ADD INDEX `country` ( `country` ( 100 ) , `location2` ( 100 ) , `location3` ( 100 ) , `location4` ( 100 ) , `location5` ( 100 ) , `location6` ( 100 ) ) ;

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to improve performance would be to add an index to country. The better way to build this would be to have an integer lookup id on the country column by adding another table of countries (country_id, country) and then changing the  country = 'spain' to country_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing UNION with UNION ALL if possible, as UNION sorts and performs de-duplication.

Comment: If I use UNION ALL I must use SELECT DISTINCT and that makes loading time even longer!

Comment: I was just saying that if you didn't need distinct results.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is I do need distinct results.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(country, price_from, location2),
INDEX(location2, price_from, location3), 
...
```

These indexes will speed things up, not only by making the `WHERE` faster, but also by being "covering".  Do *not* use "prefixing" in the indexes (as Kev suggests); it won't work.  If your locations are bigger than (100), what the heck are they?  No "country" has a name anywhere that large.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can explain why you should *not* have an array of locations implemented as columns, but instead have a separate table.

And once you have the separate table, the `UNIONs` go away, and the query becomes both simpler and faster.